# Overwriting a variable

Tags: perl

I'm still in the early days with Perl, so apologies if this is obvious.

I'm declaring a variable in Perl as shown below:

```
my $new_filename = 'nope';
```

Now if a certain condition is met (lets assume it is here), I'm attempting to reassign the value of `$new_filename` like so:

```
my $new_filename = "$common::conf{'html_dir'}/images/banners/$lc_prodid.$filetype";
```

I'm them assigning the valuu to a table:

```
my $sql_query = qq(INSERT INTO banner_image (link, title, active, imageloc, rank) VALUES ('$link_text','$banner_text','$active','$new_filename','$new_rank'));
```

The issue I have is `$new_filename` always appears as 'nope' in the database. Could anyone suggest why this might be?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using `use strict` and `use warnings`?

Comment: Don't use `my` the second time.

Comment: Use placeholders instead of interpolating them in a string. Assuming of course you are using DBI, which you should. To not do so is exposing yourself to SQL injection and bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The keyword `my` is used to *declare* a variable. That means it will tell Perl about a new variable in a given [scope](http://perlmaven.com/scope-of-variables-in-perl). You only have to do that once. After you have declared the variable, you can *assign* to it as often as you want.

```
my $foo = 'foo';
$foo = 'bar';
```

But that is not the only issue here.

> Now if a certain condition is met (lets assume it is here), I'm attempting to reassign

This probably looks like the following:

```
my $foo = 'foo';
if ( $bar ) {
  my $foo = 'bar';
}
```

Now you have **declared a new *lexical* version** of `$foo` in the smaller *scope* of those braces after the `if`. You are not overwriting the existing `$foo` in the outer *scope*. That's why the value does not change.

Here are some tips/a summary about this:

- *declare* variables in the smallest scope necessary
- *declare* variables as late as possible
- don't *declare* variables twice

Comment: It seems that no one is taught in school the policy of *"[declaring] variables in the smallest scope necessary"*. A huge number of people—it seems like the majority—declare all necessary variables in a block at the start of the file, FORTRAN style. That hasn't even been necessary in C since C99, seventeen years ago. Rather unrelated, I think there should be a purge of online tutorials that teach Perl 4 techniques, but sadly [*Brian D Foy* disagrees with me on this](http://www.learning-perl.com/2013/05/why-we-teach-the-subroutine-ampersand/). Oh, and the *purge* was a joke anyway

Comment: @bo he's going to disagree with your capitalisation of his name too. He has a tutorial for that on his website . ;-)

Comment: Tough, that's his name! I put the **D** in for him and that's plenty enough. It's not really up to him what people call him

Answer (score 2):

if you are assigning :

```
my $new_filename ="$common::conf{'html_dir'}/images/banners/$lc_prodid.$filetype";
```

inside the if clause then it is local to the scope of the if statement and will not override the variable declared outside, you need to omit the my in the second assingment